# Convert HTML Page to SVG Image via PhantomJS

Tags: html, svg, rendering, phantomjs

I am currently testing the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) system to generating screenshots of different websites...

The current rendering output of the images is a **.png** but what I need is a **SVG image**.

Does someone know a way to do this?

Comment: Try some online converter like: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg, Adobe illustrator is also highly recommended. Check out related [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861382/convert-png-to-svg) answer. Others include imagemagick's convert*, potrace*, Inkscape.

Comment: @AlvinK. Thanks for your answer but it is necessary for me to convert the html site on my own server where also the SVG result would be stored...!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005860/can-i-export-part-of-an-html-page-to-an-svg-image

Comment: Just a logical question: Why would you want a screenshot (bitmap) convert to a vector format? This is really inefficient if your website is big and it sounds like not the way to go. Maybe you can explain your use case a bit more in order to help you, finding the best technical solution.

Comment: @BausTheBig I need this vector format screenshots for a script that generating PDF files. The Screenshots are graphs which should be scalable... This is the tool I now use: [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I would rather recommend to create the PDF with Phantom.js. There is an option to export a PDF based on a HTML site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I found a tool which converting web pages into vector format screenshots: [CutyCapt](http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)  - it also rendering into other formats like png...

Have FUN! :)