# wkhtmltopdf missing SVG paths (Rendering)

Tags: html, svg, rendering, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using a image inside the HMTL code like here below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg height="291pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 291 291" width="291pt" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <defs>  <style type="text/css">*{stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;}  </style> </defs> <g id="figure_1">  <g id="patch_1">   <path d="M 0 291.4 L 291.4 291.4 L 291.4 0 L 0 0 z" style="fill:none;"></path>  </g>  <g id="axes_1">   <g id="line2d_1">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 268.427273 145.7 L 207.063636 251.984936 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_2">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 248.397453 148.307103 L 199.306544 233.335052 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_3">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 207.063636 251.984936 L 84.336364 251.984936 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_4">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 84.336364 251.984936 L 22.972727 145.7 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_5">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 92.093456 233.335052 L 43.002547 148.307103 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_6">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 22.972727 145.7 L 84.336364 39.415064 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_7">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 84.336364 39.415064 L 207.063636 39.415064 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_8">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 96.609091 55.457845 L 194.790909 55.457845 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>   <g id="line2d_9">    <path clip-path="url(#p6e64365aaf)" d="M 207.063636 39.415064 L 268.427273 145.7 " style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-width:1.2;"></path>   </g>  </g> </g> <defs>  <clipPath id="p6e64365aaf">   <rect height="270" width="270" x="10.7" y="10.7"></rect>  </clipPath> </defs></svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I'm using the wkhtmltopdf to convert it to PDF, some of the SVG paths is missing. Has anyone had the same problem? Some workaround to this issue?

I tried using the relative path, full path, base64 source and the SVG by itself within the code (as in the example).

wkhtmltopdf version: 0.12.4

[image: The image on the PDF file]

Comment: I'm not sure if it helps, but it looks like the new versions from wkhtmltopdf (bitbucket) has solved this issue.

Answer (score 6):

So not a exact solution but a far better alternative now is to use a `chrome` in headless mode

```
$ chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf test.html
[0427/011400.636954:WARNING:dns_config_service_posix.cc(174)] dns_config has unhandled options!
[0427/011400.638406:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
[0427/011400.801881:INFO:headless_shell.cc(586)] Written to file output.pdf.
```

[image: PDF output]

Also if you want better control on the process, you would use NodeJS and [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://news.ycombinator.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  await page.pdf({path: 'hn.pdf', format: 'A4'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I really need to use Wkhtmltopdf because this is just a part of a big document that is converted from html to pdf in a Python (jinja2/pdfkit).

Comment: Then I would suggest you open a bug on that repo, also chrome puppeteer has python bindings also, if I am not wrong

Comment: I did it, but still no answer. I'll look for the google puppeteer.

Comment: @IurySousa, If you do feel this answer will help don't forget to assign the bounty before it expires.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to convert the .SVG files to .PNG files before converting to .PDF. The .SVG code can be extracted via [AgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) or read the files as a string. Then use the [Svg library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/svg) to convert to .PNG as follows:

```
var svg = SvgDocument.FromSvg<SvgDocument>(svgXmlAsString);
var bitmap = svg.Draw();
var codec = "image/png".ParseImageCodecInfo();
// intermediaryStream required due to image.Save attempting read access
using (var intermediaryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(intermediaryStream, codec);
    intermediaryStream.Position = 0;
    await intermediaryStream.CopyToAsync(responseStream);
    await intermediaryStream.FlushAsync();
    await responseStream.FlushAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Joshcodes. It turned out I'm not in this project anymore, but your solution is very similar to what we did. We were looking for a way to keep in SVG format for printing quality reasons. Also, we were putting the images on a stripped table with different row colors. Which mean we needed to use an alpha for the PNG background color. But anyway, it worked this way.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Our situation was very similar with regard to print quality and the alpha background.